# Show that a unique matrix exists for the coordinate vectors in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ are two bases of a vector space
>   $V$, there exists a unique matrix $M$ such that for any $f\in V$,
>   $[f]_A=M[f]_B$.

My textbook uses this theorem without a proof, so I'm trying to show that it's true myself. Consider $[f]_A = (c_1,...,c_n)^T$ and $[f]_B=(d_1,...,d_n)^T$. How is it possible that just one, unique matrix exists that takes $[f]_B$ to $[f]_A$? Every $f$ will have a different coordinate vector under $A$ and $B$. I was thinking that it had something to do with $|A|=|B|$, but I can't justify how the matrix $M$ would look.

Comment: take a simple vector like $(1,0,0,..,0)$ in base $B$. How does it transform? What form has a matrix that does that?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that as $A$ and $B$ are independent sets (they form a basis) so the matrices $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ containing the vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively are invertible.

We have

\begin{align*}
\left[f \right]_A &= c \implies f = Ac \\
\left[f \right]_B & = d \implies f = Bd \\
\implies A c &= Bd \implies \left[f\right]_A = c = A^{-1} B d = A^{-1} B \left[f \right]_B
\end{align*}

So $M = A^{-1} B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that 
$$
b_1 = c_{11} a_1 + \cdots + c_{n1} a_n\\
\vdots \\
b_{n} = c_{n1} a_1 + \cdots + c_{nn} a_n
$$
Let $M$ be the matrix whose entries are $c_{ij}$.

If $f = f_1 b_1 + \cdots + f_n b_n$, 
(that is), $[f]_B = [f_1,\dots,f_n]$,
it follows that,
$$
f = f_1(c_{11} a_1 + \cdots + c_{n1} a_n) + \cdots +
f_n (c_{n1} a_1 + \cdots + c_{nn} a_n) \\
= (c_{11}f_1 + \cdots + c_{1n} f_n)a_1 + \cdots + 
(c_{n1}f_1 + \cdots + c_{nn} f_n)a_n
$$
This is exactly the statement
$$
[f]_A = M[f]_B
$$